# Pandas avoid double quotes in converted numeric column with appended comma

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Suppose I want to modify a column value of a Pandas dataframe by adding a closing square bracket and a comma, i.e., `],`. The column is of float type.

I am applying a custom function to the column with:

```
    df['colName'] = df['colName'].apply(parentisi2)
```

When I add just the square bracket, i.e.,

```
def parentisi2(name):
    return str(name)+"]"
```

everything is fine.

However when I add the `,`, i.e.,

```
def parentisi2(name):
    return str(name)+"],"
```

when saving to file also double quotes are inserted.
For example instead of having `9.336669722189999],` I get `"9.336669722189999],"`

How can I avoid that?

Comment: No. Because you're saying a `csv` file, which is separated by commas. If you write that comma without the quotes, then how are you gonna now when the comma is part of a column (i.e part of the id+`],` thing) or when it's a separator between columns ?

Comment: Why are you adding the comma yourself? pandas will do that for you

Comment: It is a comma of the string,  not a separating comma. However I would like the string without the double quotes. however @rafaelc is right, I realize it now that without the `"` it is taken as a field separator

Comment: maybe you could use ; as a delimiter instead of , for your csv file - this way you don't need the quotation marks

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I had misread OP's intention. This answer handles the separator in the csv export.

It works if you use another separator. Below I have used `;`

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'colName': [0.1, 0.2]})

def parentisi2(name):
    return str(name)+"],"

df['parentisi'] = df['colName'].apply(lambda x: parentisi2(x))
df['parentisi'] = df['parentisi'].astype(str)
df.to_csv('parentisi.csv',
          sep = ';')
```

Comment: You are absolutely right... I had misread OP's intention. Updated answer to solve the csv export issue.